# Is using a enum class inside of a class class un-necessary

Tags: c++, class, enums, enumeration

I should start by saying I'm fairly new to OOP.  I am trying to write a portable class which will probably be used in multiple programs.  The class requires multiple enumerated lists to store information which are only relevant to the class so I was planning on nesting the enum inside the class. My questions are

- Is there any reason to use an `enum class` inside a class, or should I just use `enum`? Just curious.  I posted sample code for reference below.
- Is there any reason why it would be a really bad idea to make enums in a class public?

---

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Color {
    red     = 0,
    green   = 1,
    blue    = 2
};

class CodeLibray {
public:
    enum Color2 {
        red     = 0,
        green   = 1,
        blue    = 2
    };
    enum class Color3 {
        red     = 0,
        green   = 1,
        blue    = 2
    };
    Color color;
    Color2 color2; 
    Color3 color3;
}; 

int main(){
    CodeLibray c;
    c.color = Color::red;
    c.color2 = CodeLibray::Color2::blue;
    c.color3 = CodeLibray::Color3::blue;
}
```

Comment: "*Also, If I want enums to be accessible for assigning public member values but I do not want values in the enum to be changed is this possible?*" ... I don't know what you mean by that. Are you talking about member variables of `enum` types, or the enumerators themselves (`red`, etc)? If a member variable is publicly accessible for assignment, then it's publicly modifiable too, since assignment is how you modify it. So again, I'm not really sure what you're getting at.

Comment: I modified the second question for clarification.

Comment: "*make enums in a class public?*" The enumeration itself or variables of that enumeration type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Is there any reason to use an `enum class` inside a class, or should I just use `enum`? Just curious.  I posted sample code for
>     reference below.

It's pretty obvious that the `enum` values defined inside `CodeLibray` would become ambigous if you omit the `enum class` there.

> - Also, If I want enums to be accessible for assigning public member values but I do not want values in the enum to be changed is this
>     possible?

I don't fully understand what you mean. Just a shot in the dark, something like the following?

```
enum Color2 {
    red     = ::red,
           // ^^ Refer to the enum declaration in the global namespace
    green   = ::green,
    blue    = ::blue
};
enum class Color3 {
    red     = ::red,
    green   = ::green,
    blue    = ::blue
};
```

Comment: Well, it wasn't all that obvious to me, but I get it now.  So based on this, If I have multiple enums in the class it probably makes sense to use "enum class" so I don't run into issues with ambiguous definitions. However if there was only one enum required, or a limited number it probably shouldn't matter since its scoped inside the class right?

Comment: @mreff555 _"it probably shouldn't matter since its scoped inside the class right?"_ Yes. But you should always prefer `enum class`, because it makes the code more clear and easier to read.